# For a 2x2 matrix A satisfying $A^k=I$, compute $e^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a 2x2 matrix A satisfying $A^k=I$, compute $e^A$ 
Oh, the exponential of a matrix is: $e^A=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{i!}A^i$

---

I thought I'd solved the $e^A$ form but I actually did something really silly, now I'm a little stuck.

If $A^k=I$ then $A^{k+1}=A$ and we have a cycle forming, so we will get:

$$\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}\frac{1}{(kj+i)!}A^i$$

(Or something like this form, I don't have paper to hand and just spotted that now)

Is this what the question wants? It doesn't use the 2x2 property.

I believe the answer lies in finding an expression for the inner summation, I can do this for two terms (think of $e+e^{-1}$ all the odd power leave)

Comment: How is $k$ defined...any positive integer?

Comment: Yes @TylerHG. Although if it were negative nothing would change.  Some sort of integer certainly - but not-integer powers make no sense.

Comment: Is $A$ known to be real? Or can it be complex as well?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen lets stick with real - although please do share any thoughts on the complex case (this is interesting to me!)

Comment: On second thought whether it is real or not may not make much difference here :-)

Comment: I would consider posting the second part as another question. Your call, of course! Mind you, if $A^k=I$, then $AB=BA=I$ with $B=A^{k-1}$, so...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm glad you've locked on the second half of the question! What's the first part trying to demonstrate.

Comment: cf. [Lagrange-Sylvester expansions, Sec 6](http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2014/084/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A^k=I$ then $A$ is full rank.  However there is no necessary relation between the rank $n$ and $k$.

E.g. a $2\times 2$ real orthogonal matrix $A$ can have arbitrarily large multiplicative order (think roots of unity), but also $k \gt 0$ can be the order of an arbitrary size matrix (say $n\times n$).

**Matrix exponentiation by diagaonlization**

Among the various ways [to evaluate matrix exponential](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf), a diagonal matrix $D = \operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is an easily computed case:

$$ e^D = \operatorname{diag}(e^{d_1},\ldots,e^{d_n}) $$

Also the exponential function conserves similarity relationships because of the power series definition, so if $A = T D T^{-1}$, then:

$$ e^A = T e^D T^{-1} $$

Not every matrix is diagonalizable, but if $A^k = I$ for $k \gt 0$, then $A$ is diagonalizable.  Because $X^k - 1$ has no repeated roots, the *minimal polynomial* of $A$ must divide $X^k - 1$ and also have no repeated roots.  From this [it follows that $A$ is diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)#Applications).

**Solutions of $A^k=I$ that are real $2\times 2$ matrices**

In particular for the $2\times 2$ real matrices, either the minimum exponent $k$ is one, which implies $A=I$ and $e^I = \operatorname{diag}(e,\ldots,e)$, or the minimum exponent $k$ is greater than one (the multiplicative order of $A$).  In the latter case a $2\times 2$ real matrix $A$ will have a conjugate pair of complex eigenvalues that are *primitive* $k$th roots of unity:

$$e^{\pm 2\pi im/k} = \cos(2\pi m/k) \pm i\sin(2\pi m/k)$$

where integer $0 \lt m \lt k$ is coprime to $k$.

Then for a suitable diagonalizing similarity transformation $T$:

$$ A = T \pmatrix{e^{2\pi im/k}  & 0 \cr
                       0 & e^{-2\pi im/k} \cr } T^{-1} $$

Per the earlier discussion:

$$ e^A = T \pmatrix{e^{e^{2\pi im/k}}  & 0 \cr
                         0 & e^{e^{-2\pi im/k}} \cr } T^{-1} $$

Comment: Can you give an example of that second line, for example a 2x2 matrix of determinant 1 (or -1, missed that in my Q) of order 5 or 6?

Comment: @Alec: The rotation matrix
$$A=\pmatrix{\cos(2\pi/n)&-\sin(2\pi/n)\cr\sin(2\pi/n)&\cos(2\pi/n)\cr}$$ has order $n$. Here $n$ can be any positive integer.

Comment: I feel really silly now - thanks @JyrkiLahtonen - I'd also like to note that this has not answered my question.It's simply shown a trail of thought for my question is totally wrong

Comment: It would likely help me to address your concerns to know with more exactitude what properties of $A$ (size $2\times 2$ or $n\times n$, or satisfying $A^k=I$ for some $k\gt 0$) should be assumed.

Comment: A is 2x2, as stated in the question, I have been told that $A^k=I$ for some k, and to find $e^A$

Comment: I don't mean that in a short way I just am not sure what isn't clear.

Comment: @hardmath that is the question, do you want me to edit first?

Comment: You beat me!!!!

Comment: @MartinArgerami: The argument is not that $A$ has no repeated eigenvalues, but that its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots, a condition that is equivalent to being diagonalizable.

Comment: You are right. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If the two eigenvalues are distinct, then $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix, and its eponential is similar (with the same conjugating matrix) to the exponential of that diagonal matrix, which is found by just exponentiating each entry.

If both eigenvalues are the same, say $\lambda$, then $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$, so $e^A=e^{\lambda I}e^{A-\lambda I}=e^\lambda(I+(A-\lambda I))=e^\lambda(A-(\lambda-1)I)$.

If the matrices are real, then in the latter case, the eigenvalue must be $\pm 1$, in which case $e^A=eA$ or $e^A=e^{-1}(A+2I)$, according to whether it's $+1$ or $-1$. In the former case, the eigenvalues are either imaginary and complex conjugates of each other, or they're $+1$ and $-1$, and you can compute the exponential of the corresponding diagonal matrix accordingly.

I don't think you can say much more without more information; if $k$ is the order of $A$, then you can narrow down the possible roots of unity that the eigenvalues can be, but you still don't know exactly what they are, or what the conjugating matrix is.

Comment: Diagonalising this matrix is very difficult (det = +/- 1, very little to go on, certainly not generalise) I think the key lies in that inner summand, for example one part of it is $I\sum^\infty_{i=0}\frac{1}{(nk)!}$ this needs a closed form. Notice that $e+e^{-1}=\sum^\infty_{i=0}\frac{1}{(2i)!}$ I think the key lies here. if $k=2$ we get $2e^A=(e+\frac{1}{e})I+(e-\frac{1}{e})A$

Answer (score 0):

At the time I was asked the same question I proposed a bit different solution. If we speak about $\mathbb R^2$ then such an operator is plane isometry so it's reflexion or rotation. In appropriate basis reflexion and rotation have matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
  cos \alpha & -sin\alpha \\
  sin\alpha & cos \alpha
 \end{pmatrix}$, $\alpha = 2\pi/k$.

As for the reflexion its exponent is easily calculated by substition of its matrix into series definition. For the rotation we may swith to $\mathbb C$ where rotation is just multiplication operator $Az = e^{i\alpha}z$. Its exponent is $e^{e^{i\alpha}}$. Projecting back to $\mathbb R^2$ we get $e^{cos\alpha}\begin{pmatrix}
  cos(sin\alpha) & -sin(sin\alpha) \\
  sin(sin\alpha) & cos(sin\alpha)
 \end{pmatrix}$.